# Use configuration file from VS in powershell to deploy Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I have created configuration files (Dev.json & QA.json) to deploy Azure Data Factory artifacts to different environments using Visual Studio as given here [https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2017/01/using-azure-data-factory-configuration-files/.](http://here)

Deploying using VS is time taking task, so I decided to use powershell.

Now, I want use the same configuration files (Dev.json & QA.json) to be used for deployment using powershell. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: As I understand the current PowerShell cmdlets for ADF only generate the JSON for you and output the file. They don't actually perform the deployment to Azure. Thanks for reading my blog :-)

Comment: Ohh is it so..I thought New-AzureRmDataFactory command will create & deploy as well. For eg:- New-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline $df -File .\MyFirstPipelinePSH.json will deploy the pipeline as well

Answer (score 1):

You're right you can create all the objects in data factory with PowerShell, but at this time there is no way to automatically apply the config file to it.

Config files are a project level object and could have elements that apply to any ADF object. As such they are only used in the VS publish wizard.

You could incorporate the config details into your PowerShell script by using the ConvertFrom-JSON cmdlet and parsing the entries against the ADF objects you're creating.